# Isn't $f_n(x)=\frac{{n^2}\ln x}{x^n}$ with $x\geq1$ uniformly convergent by $T$-test?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

One Dr. showed to me that the function $f_n(x)=\dfrac{{n^2}\ln x}{x^n}$, $x\geq1$ is not uniformly convergent by $T$-test, but I showed it to converge to $0$ anyway.
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}T_n=\lim_{x\to \infty} \left[\sup_{x\geq1}\left|f_n(x)-f(x)\right|\right]=\dfrac{3}{4e^{2n}}=0$$ and hence convergent by $T$-test.
Thus either of us has to be wrong, please which of us is wrong? Am really waiting.

Comment: Show us your proof of convergence

Answer (score 3):

I think that you are wrong.

Write $f_n(x) = \dfrac{n^2\ln x}{x^n}$, $x\geq 1$. It is clear that $f_n(x) \to 0$ for every $n$, but the convergence is not uniform: we have
$$
\sup_{x\geq 1}|f_n(x)-0| \geq f_n(e^{1/n}) = \frac{n}{e} \to +\infty
$$

(Notice that this was not a lucky guess: $x=e^{1/n}$ cancels $f_n'(x)$)

---

*Exercise.* Are the following sequences of functions uniformly convergent on $[1,\infty)$?
$$
g_n(x) = \dfrac{n\ln x}{x^n}, \qquad h_n(x) = \dfrac{\ln x}{x^n}
$$

Comment: Ju'x, that is how he showed to me too, but I thought you are going to have $\dfrac{n-lnx}{x^{n+1}}=0$ along the way which gives $x=e^n$?

Comment: No, it is $\dfrac{n^2(1-n\ln x)}{x^{n+1}} = 0$. But either way, you should be able to see that $e^{1/n}$ provides a counter-example to the uniform convergence.

Comment: OMG, Ju'x I think I deserve punishment for dis-including brackets after the elementary differentiation and wrote $\dfrac{n^2.1-nlnx}{x^{n+1}}$ instead.  Anyway, I got the mistake now, thanks.